# How can I bring a Player to ignore collision with another GameObject in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Im currently trying to code a health system for my game and I want my Player GameObject to ignore collision with the Health Potion GameObject if the Player has max health. My problem is that I cannot simply turn off the collision between the Player Layer and Health Potion Layer because I only want to ignore collision if the Player has Max Health. I tried doing it myself but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
public class ExampleCodeUA : MonoBehaviour{

public int PlayerMaxHealth = 100, PlayerCurrentHealth;
public HealthBar healthBar;

private void Start()
{
    PlayerCurrentHealth = PlayerMaxHealth;
}

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("HealthPotion"))
    {
        if (PlayerCurrentHealth == PlayerMaxHealth)
        {
            Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(6, 7);
        }
        else if (PlayerCurrentHealth > 50)
        {
            GetHealth(PlayerMaxHealth - PlayerCurrentHealth);
        }
        else if (PlayerCurrentHealth <= 50)
        {
            GetHealth(50);
        }

    }
}

void GetHealth(int healing)
{
    PlayerCurrentHealth += healing;
    healthBar.SetHealth(PlayerCurrentHealth);
}
```

}

Comment: Can't you ignore collisions between those layers when player has max health and restore collisions when player loses some health?

Comment: I've tried doing that but even when the Player had less than max health there was no collision between him and the health potion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to modify your physics configuration at runtime. What you could do to avoid the collision... is to make it impossible, by having nothing to collide with. Both of your objects have a collider. What you could do is to disable all existing HealthPotion colliders by modifying their code. An implementation could be the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generics;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthPotion : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static List<HealthPotion> _existingPotions = new List<HealthPotion>();

    public static void EnablePotionsCollider(bool value)
    {
        foreach (var potion in _existingPotions)
        {
            potion._collider.enabled = value;
        }
    }

    private Collider _collider;

    void Awake()
    {
        _collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        _existingPotions.Add(this);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        _existingPotions.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call the method when you want to enable/disable by doing

```
HealthPotion.EnablePotionsCollider(value you want);
```

Comment: When I use this code I get two errors in line 9 at EnablePotionsCollider: Method must have a return type and more than one protection modifier. In what script am I supposed to write this? The player or the health potion script?

Comment: I wrote it without having a compiler so I forget the return type (here void, we don't want to return anything). I'm editing the answer. What I wrote should be written in the potion script, and call the method at the bottom of my reply from your player script when you want to enable/disable collisions

Comment: It works!! Thank you! I've been trying to solve this for hours and nothing worked. Maybe one day I'll solve a problem myself without google :D

Comment: Sure you will, that's why you learn. I recommend you to make sure you understand what the code does and not to simply copy paste it ;)

Comment: Yes, I did that. I actually didn't know what lists were so I looked up a tutorial for it.